# How to open a .cto file for editing?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am following instruction on "Developer Tutorial for creating a Hyperledger Composer solution". After creating business network structure step 2 asks to open .cto file and edit it. How do I open the .cto file? Do I use terminal or viscose to open it and how?

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

you can open the .cto file by using any editor that you want. The one I use is atom (https://atom.io/).

Once you have downloaded and installed atom, open it then navigate to where your file is in your terminal and enter the following command `atom enter_CTO_filename_here.cto`

You can also open the file from the atom UI by navigating to where the file is by going File -> Open -> then select your file...

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `.cto` file in notepad, wordpad or notepad++.

But [Atom IDE](https://atom.io/) is a better option to do that. You can even view and edit your `script.js` file in the atom and deploy them back to the composer afterwards.

You can also add hyperledger-composer-plugin in Atom as it provides syntax highlighting and snippets for Composer in Atom.

[Steps to install atom plugin from the Atom market place:](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-atom-plugin#install-atom-plugin-from-the-atom-market-place)

1. Open Atom application
2. Open the Install Packages/Themes by click Packages --> Settings View and select Install Packages/Themes
3. Select Install on the Settings menu
4. Type composer-atom-plugin or composer-* in the Packages search field and you should see the composer-atom-plugin on the list
5. Select the composer-atom-plugin from the install packages and click on Install button to install it.
   You should now have syntax highlighting for Composer .cto files.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using [VSCode editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)  - Hyperledger Composer has a plugin for syntax highlighting for model files, as described here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - see 'Step 3: Set up your IDE'